# Linux (Ubuntu 12.04). Setup OpenSSL and osslsigncode

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openssl

I'm a beginner in using Linux.
I have already installed OpenSSL 1.0.1 and after installing osslsigncode I have:

```
osslsigncode -v    
>osslsigncode 1.5.1, using:
 OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
 libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
        no libgsf available
```

When I install OpenSSL 1.0.2a and after that I recompile osslsigncode tool so that it is still using OpenSSL 1.0.1.
Tell me please how I should install OpenSSL 1.0.2a or setup osslsigncode so osslsigncode will use it.

I would be very grateful for the help.
Thanks.